# Function linear over convex combinations once again

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, affine-geometry

I asked recently here about functions $L:X\rightarrow X$ satisfying
$$ L(ax+by)=aL(x)+bL(y)$$
for $a,b$ such that $a+b=1$. I know now that it also holds
$$ L(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i L(x_i)$$
for $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i =1$ and $n>2$.
I'm wondering now if the definition implies also
$$ L(ax)=aL(x)$$
for *every* $a$, not necessarily $a=1$?

Comment: If $L\colon X\to X$ satisfies your property, then the map $L'\colon x\mapsto L(x)-L(0)$ also satisfies your property and maps $0\mapsto 0$, so will satisfy $L'(\lambda x)=\lambda L'(x)$.  If $X$  is a vector space over a field of characteristic not $2$,  then use $\lambda=2$ to get $L'(x+y)=L'(x)+L'(Y)$).  Thus the functions satisfying your property are precisely the ones of the form $L(x)=Tx+v$ for a linear map $T\colon X\to X$ and a vector $v\in X$.  Conversely if $X$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$, then any function $X\mapsto X$ will satisfy your property!

Comment: So, you're proving that $L'$ is a linear map? But how do you prove that $L'(x+y)=L'(x)+L'(y)$? I don't get it.

Comment: $L'(x+y)=L'(2(\frac x2+\frac y2))=2L'(\frac x2+\frac y2)=2(\frac12L'(x)+\frac12L'(y))=L'(x)+L'(y)$.  Notice this only works in characteristic not $2$.

Comment: Heh, yes, I've just figured it out and was going to write that you rahter meant $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}$ :)

Comment: I wasn't clear, but by $\lambda$ I meant the one in the previous line, so we use that multiplication by $2$ commutes with $L'$.  It is a bit weird that characteristic 2 is so drastically different - all permutations rather than just affine maps, especially as your earlier question showed that $2$ was in some sense not important to the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the function $L(x)=x+v$ for some constant non-zero vector $v\in X$.

Then $L(0x)=L(0)=0+v=v\neq 0=0L(x)$.